# Is there a diffeomorphism between any algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F_2}$ and some subset of $\Bbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

I'm looking for a way to translate between differential equations and their solutions over some algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F_2}$ and some subset of $\Bbb{C}$.

The algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F_2}$ that I'm using is the algebra formed by taking the set {$1^r : r \geq 0$} along with their sums (mod 2) and exponentials taken to non-negative powers (for instance $(1^{\frac{1}{2}} + 1^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}$) along with the definition that $x^0 = 0 \forall x$.  To complete this field, I'm using the metric $d(1^r)=r$ (when r is between 0 and 1), $d(x+y) = d(x) + d(y)$ as long as x+y is in lowest terms, and $d(x^r) = r*d(x)$ (when r is between 0 and 1).

The algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F_2}$ that I'm using, however, is not extremely important.  What is important is that it's diffeomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb{C}$.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to begin with this problem.  Any help would be appreciated.  However, my next attempt will be at mapping the elements with d(x) = r to the circle of radius r starting with $1^r \to r$ for $0 \leq r \leq 1$.

Comment: Hw do you put a differentiable structure on $\overline{\Bbb F_2}$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : Using my definitions, $1^{d\theta}$ are infinitesimals.  If p(x) is an n-th degree polynomial with $c_n$ as the coefficient of the $x^n$ term, then $f(x+dx) = f(x) + c_n * dx^n$.

Edit:  Oh, you should note that $dx^2 > dx$, which is counter intuitive.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : The Leibniz Rule doesn't hold.  I have $d(f * g) = df * dg$.  However, (correct me if I'm wrong), I don't think that stops me from having a theory of differential equations.

Comment: It's totally unclear how "the algebra formed by..." would actually form an algebra, and why it would be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: (what you *can* do is forget addition and observe there is isomorphism of *multiplicative monoids* between the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$ and the submonoid of the complexes consisting of the *odd* roots of unity together with zero) (or as rings, view the closure as the quotient of the ring of cyclotomic integers by a maximal ideal over $2$)

Comment: You really need to say more precisely what you mean by "diffeomorphism".  In standard terminology, it only makes sense to talk about a diffeomorphism between two spaces if they are differentiable manifolds.  So how is $\overline{\mathbb{F}_2}$ a differentiable manifold?  What are the charts?  Or do you have some other notion of "diffeomorphism" in mind?